# Can a website tell what device you're using?

Tags: ip-address, mac-address, cookies

If I were to visit a website on different occasions and from different IP addresses but from the same device, could a website potentially tell?

If so, would deleting cookies prevent this?

Answer (score 2):

The answer is yes, and it no longer requires cookies to do so:

Various technologies exist to track users, in addition to cookies. Some fingerprint a browser based on differences in each browser's rendering of a site, since each browser will load the page slightly different due to screen size, plugins, etc. From the [Electronic Frontier Foundation](https://www.eff.org/deeplinks/2014/07/white-house-website-includes-unique-non-cookie-tracker-despite-privacy-policy):

> ProPublica reported on new research by a team at KU Leuven and
>   Princeton on canvas fingerprinting. One of the most intrusive users of
>   the technology is a company called AddThis, who are employing it in
>   “shadowing visitors to thousands of top websites, from WhiteHouse.gov
>   to YouPorn.com.” Canvas fingerprinting allows sites to get even more
>   identifying information than we had previously warned about with our
>   Panopticlick fingerprinting experiment.
>
> Canvas fingerprinting exploits the fact that different browsers have
>   slightly different algorithms, parameters, and hardware for turning
>   text into pictures on your screen (or more specifically, into an HTML
>   5 canvas object that the tracker can read). ... The main distinction
>   is that the canvas fingerprint can’t be blocked by cookie management
>   techniques, or erased with your other cookies. ...

And from [Forbes](http://www.forbes.com/sites/adamtanner/2013/06/17/the-web-cookie-is-dying-heres-the-creepier-technology-that-comes-next/)

> To combat the cookie’s flaws, advertisers and publishers are
>   increasingly turning to something called fingerprinting. This
>   technique allows a web site to look at the characteristics of a
>   computer such as what plugins and software you have installed, the
>   size of the screen, the time zone, fonts and other features of any
>   particular machine. These form a unique signature just like random
>   skin patterns on a finger. The Electronic Frontier Foundation has
>   found that 94% of browsers that use Flash or Java – which enable key
>   features in Internet browsing – had unique identities.
>
> Fingerprinting may prove a more robust tracking technology than
>   cookies because the user’s identity endures even if they erase their
>   cookies. Making changes to your software and settings only makes you
>   more identifiable, not less. An EFF study several years ago found that
>   it is easy to track when someone changes their profiles by adding
>   software updates, for example.

Forbes also references the EFF site https://panopticlick.eff.org/ to show a user what information their browser reports that can be used to create a unique browser fingerprint without a cookie.

Finally Internet Carriers have introduced their own tracking tools, such as Verizon's *Unique Identifier Header* as Wired describes [Verizon’s ‘Perma-Cookie’ Is a Privacy-Killing Machine](http://www.wired.com/2014/10/verizons-perma-cookie/)

> Verizon Wireless has been subtly altering the web traffic of its
>   wireless customers for the past two years, inserting a string of about
>   50 letters, numbers, and characters into data flowing between these
>   customers and the websites they visit.
>
> The company—one the country’s largest wireless carriers, providing
>   cell phone service for about 123 million subscribers—calls this a
>   Unique Identifier Header, or UIDH. It’s a kind of short-term serial
>   number that advertisers can use to identify you on the web, and it’s
>   the lynchpin of the company’s internet advertising program.

Each of these technologies provide means to track regardless of the presence of cookies, and in the case of UIDH header-injection - regardless of any browser setting.

Answer (score 0):

It is indeed possible for website to detect what device you are using. [Here](http://demo.mobiledetect.net/) is a link to a demo of MobileDetect, a PHP library that determines what your device is. Websites use something called a user agent (UA for short) to determine what your device is. Cookies have absolutely nothing to do with device detection. The only way to hide what device you are using would be to spoof your UA so the website thinks it is something else.

Comment: I don't think that is what he is asking. He is talking about whether a website can tell if you are the same person/device if your IP address changes, not whether a website can tell what hardware you have.

Comment: @James DavidB is correct though. It is up to the browser to relay that information. Changing device but using the same browser will cause different data to be sent, unless that data is spoofed.

Comment: @James If that is in fact what he is asking, then I suppose it would be possible for a website to tell if unique identifying cookies are stored on the device.